# MYSQL - Insert results in table from two selects

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Let's say that i have 2 different select statements that provide one column, each of them. 
let's suppose that the select statements provide the below data:

```
SELECT 1            SELECT 2
|id|                 |nr|
----                 ----
456                   14
234                   5
512                   26
678                   67
987                   87
632                   24
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make a query to insert this data like below:

```
my_table
|  id  |  nr  |  col3  | ...
   456    14     ...
   234    5      ...
   512    26     ...
   678    67     ...
  ...
```

I have to mention that in my selects I am using multiple rows subqueries.

THank you a lot!

Comment: Do they produce the same number of rows each? Is there any relation between the two? Use temp tables with an identity column in each, then join the 2 tables on the identity column to insert into `my_table`.

Comment: yeah, they produce the same number of rows... no relation between them

Comment: So can you use the temp tables as I suggested?

Comment: there is my problem, I tried to join them into one table but it provide me a Cartesian product. every select returns like 140 rows and join provides like 20000 rows

Comment: Can you use `ROW_NUMBER()` to produce an index from each data set?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use variables to enumerate the values and then a `join`:

```
select . . . 
from (select s.*, (@rn1 := @rn1 + 1) as rn
      from (<select 1>) s cross join
           (select @rn1 := 0) params
     ) s1 join
     (select s.*, (@rn2 := @rn2 + 1) as rn
      from (<select 2>) s cross join
           (select @rn2 := 0) params
     ) s2
     on s1.rn = s2.rn;
```

I would suggest putting an explicit `order by` in each of the subqueries.